# What would happen with a 25W bulb (g4) in a 20W socket?

Tags: watts, halogen

I have a 20W (12V) desk lamp and a 25W (500 lm) bulb, type = G4/halogen.

I know putting a 75W bulb in a 60W socket can damage it or cause it to break.

In my situation there is only 5W difference.

1. Would the extra 5W damage the lamp?
2. Is it very dangerous?
3. What could happen if I put the 25W bulb in?

I can't find a suitable answer on google so I thought I better be safe and ask stack exchange.

Edit:

Here is a picture of the lamp if it helps:

[image]

Comment: It all about the ability to dissipate the heat.

Comment: If it could safely work at 25 W then it would be rated at 25 W. Think melting, catching fire, that sort of stuff.

Comment: i just opened up the front of the lamp and the ring on the outside says 12v/20w but inside the connecter for the bulb says 100w @AndrewMorton

Comment: @YoloGamer You need to follow the rating of the whole luminaire, not just the socket.

Comment: >>>  "I know putting a 75w bulb in a 60w socket can damage it or cause it to break. In my situation there is only 5w difference."     75W in a 60W socket is 25% over-power rating.   25W in a 20W socket is the same --- 25% over.   It's not absolute values that matter.  If you put a 5W bulb in a 1W socket, that's only 4W over so it's OK??  Probably not

Comment: @AndrewMorton this is an old lamp and i have replaced all of the old wiring inside and out with new thicker cable that can handle over 500w.

Comment: Whats the temperature rating of the wire you used???    If you connected it right up to the socket, that may be bad.   Those sockets usually have a silicon-jacketed wire to handle the heat generated by the bulb.

Comment: @KyleB this is an old lamp and i have replaced all of the old wiring inside and out with new thicker cable that can handle over 500w ,also i have removed the transformer because i am using a 12 power source that can handle 250w

Comment: IMO, I'd go for it.  Just watch for burning plastic smell.   If you use it for a while at full power in a hot room and no odor, you're probably OK.  The rating may have been a limit for the original transformer as much as for heat dissipation.

Comment: @YoloGamer It could be dangerous just because of the power supply: 20 A of current flowing if the arms are shorted could weld something to them.

Comment: @KyleB the wiring directly connected to the bulb socket is a special wiring that is high heat resistant

Comment: @AndrewMorton the power supply can only supply 7/8A also it is limited to 12v

Comment: @YoloGamer I was going on the earlier comment that mentioned "a 12 power source that can handle 250w": 250 W / 12 V = 20.8 A.

Comment: so after all of this do you think it would be ok to put the 25w bulb in to my lamp?

Comment: @AndrewMorton i'm sorry to ask but can you give a safety recommendation. 1(very dangerous) - 10(very safe)

Comment: Halogen bulbs generally run hot enough to start a fire regardless. So that glass cover is non-negotiable.

Comment: Just switch to an LED.  They work very well and they're cheap.  Not as cheap as a halogen bulb, but won't get hot.        https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1313&_nkw=G4+LED&_sacat=0

Comment: @KyleB the problem with led g4 bulbs they don't have a high lumen number but the bulb i have now is 500lm. i cant find cant led bulbs that can deliver 500lm

Comment: I found 500 lm LED G4 5W 6000’K but you may want 5000’K or less. $24 Cdn /10pc

Comment: @YoloGamer I am not a qualified electrical engineer so I cannot give a safety recommedation. I am also not an insurance company inspector looking to invalidate your insurance after modified electrical equipment caused your house to burn down.

Answer (score 2):

75 W om a 60W socket is 25% oversized

25W in a 20W socket is 25% oversized. so just as bad.

There's a good chance that something will break, and it might be the transformer in the base of that lamp, that part is most unlikely to have 25% excess capacity.

Answer (score 2):

It may void your insurance cover. Or not.

I'd expect it to work well enough.
It may not.

A 5W LED lamp may produce 500 lumen (100 l/W)
A 6W one should.
A 7W one almost certainly will./

I'd look at the illumination patterns of LED and Halogen bulbs.
The Halogen radiates upwards and downwards, with the upwards light reflected downwards.
Depending on design an LED bulb may have all light radiated in one direction - and the radiation angle may in any case be smaller than for a Halogen lamp.
Comparing actual results may prove useful.

A Halogen lamp will reduce in output over hundreds to a few thousand hours.
A reputable source LED lamp should have close top constant apparent output for 50,000+ hours.

The human eye/brain does not readily distinguish differences of illumination of perhaps 50%.  All else being equal - if you have a say 500 lumen and 350 lumen lamp, if each is viewed independently, almost nobody could tell which was which.

---

### **WARNING**

In most cases lamps of that type have the 12V supply voltage present on the two uninsulated arms. This is a potential fire hazard even when limited energy power supplies are used. If the power supply is capable of supplying current well in excess of the lamp requirement the fire risk will be higher. This may invalidate your insurance cover, regardless of bulb wattage. A fuse (or better) is recommended.

---

**Reference:**

I have so far been able to find a non-paywalled version of this paper, which describes the hazards due to low voltage low energy sources.

Vicars, Richard. Small, James. Munson, Terry. Parrish, Christopher.
Low Voltage: The Incompetent Ignition Source Dispelling the Myth. (2010).